# Is there a way to smoothly update window size in floating mode on Chrome OS

Tags: android, google-chrome-os, androidappsonchromeos

So basically I need to update current floating window bounds (width, height, and maybe position) from already running Activity. I need this to smoothly transition from one screen to another. Is there a recommended way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Animate transitions of a generic View you should consider that all Animations works as expected ONLY if there is enough RESERVED VISUAL SPACE to execute them. If there isn't enough visual space the animation/transition became slow/laggy because one or more boundaries should be changed at each Frame of Animation.

A floating window (usually) has its View boundaries set to exactly what you see, and no any more visual space is reserved to size it to a bigger dimension. So a "RootView.animate().scaleXby(2f)" method cannot work as expected.

To the opposite side you CAN successfully animate a **size-down** because the bigger dimension is the initial one of the RootView, so you can call "RootView.animate().scaleXby(0.5f)..." to reduce its size without any problem. The only issue is that a transparent space will remains around your new-sized floating window. To fix this: at the end of animation you can calculate the size-difference and do a "dirty" LayoutParams update to resize the floating window accordling to new dimensions.

So the best solution (to scale it UP or DOWN) is:

1. the Floating Window SHOULD be contained in a Transparent ViewGroup as its parent
2. set that Transparent ViewGroup to fullscreen dimensions and move the content (the part you really want to resize) to the same coords of before
3. do all animation/resize stuff/procedure
4. when the animation/resize is finished....
5. ...set the Transparent ViewGroup to new size/coords, and...
6. ...set the Content Width/Height to match its parent (that Transparent ViewGroup)

(small flickering effects COULD be appear during initial and final phase, but it's the small cost we need to pay)